# Update .net standard PackageReference from command line

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core, .net-standard

We have a bunch of fast moving internal nuget packages.

We want the consumers of these packages to always be on the latest version. We currently do this on our CI system by running nuget update on the command line before build.

However we now are moving to .net standard/core. When we run nuget update on a .net standard csproj we get the following error:

> Unable to update. The project does not contain a packages.config file.

Nuget still seems to be expecting a packages.config even though this has been dropped for .net core/standard csproj files.

How do we update PackageReferences to the latest version using the commandline for .net core/standard csproj projects?

UPDATE:
I've created a bug report incase this is a bug here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4945

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround, you should be able to run `dotnet remove package` followed by `dotnet add package` to update to the latest version of some package.